# The reference to was not found in the list of this projects references

Tags: c#

I have two projects `ProjectName` and `ProjectName.Test`

In `ProjectName.Test` below error is populated while building the solution.

> ProjectName.accessor: The reference to 'ProjectName.dll' was not found in the list of this projects references

I am not getting why this error occurrs. Reference of `ProjectName.dll` is already present in `ProjectName.Test`

Comment: So, do you mean ProjectName.dll is not able to be found in the ProjectName.Test project? Did you properly reference the dll?

Comment: Verify the physical .DLL in the references folder if it is a DLL reference. If it is a project reference, make sure the project is built without any errors before building the .Test project

Answer (score 0):

A possibility to explore: The problem is with the references in the accessor file in the Unit Test project under the "Test References" folder. Consider removing the accessor file and refactor the unit tests to remove the need to access a private property.

Reference: [See answer from Gerardo](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0edbe76d-dc42-4425-8147-e4261ce1764e/unit-test-project-not-compiling-with-msbuild-4-accessor-missing-reference?forum=msbuild)

One approach would be to use the [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute.